# Run buildbot builder on one of the available slaves

Tags: buildbot

I have a buildbot 0.8.6p1 configured. There is one master and one slave, so far.
It is possible to configure several slaves:

```
c['slaves'] = [
    BuildSlave("eng-hwsim-n1", "123")
    BuildSlave("eng-hwsim-n2", "123")
]
```

It is also possible to add `slave` or `slaves` to the array of builders:

```
c['builders'].append(
    BuilderConfig(name="runnightly-top",
        slavenames=["eng-hwsim-n1", "eng-hwsim-n2"],
        factory=fac_nightly_top,
        builddir='../../runnightly-top',
        slavebuilddir='runnightly-top'))
```

In this case, will buildbot run the same builder on *all* slaves or *one of the* slaves? 
Is there a way to configure buildbot to run a builder on one of the slaves, whichever is available/least loaded/etc?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Did you manage to get the solution? Neither the accepted answer nor the linked questions are helping me. I can't manage to make buildbot choose one of the slaves from a pool of slaves, which is basically your last question: `Is there a way to configure buildbot to run a builder on one of the slaves, whichever is available/least loaded/etc?`

Comment: @Math: eventually I gave up on 0.8.6 and installed 0.8.8. It is much more stable. And thus this BBot does pick up a slave from a pool. Just follow the manual or what I listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builder will only build with one slave from the pool of slaves. If I understand correctly, this is the behavior you desire.

Comment: How does it select the slave from the pool?

Comment: I believe it's just a round robin of the ones that aren't busy. If you want to control it specifically you can use the nextSlave  option in your builder configuration. http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.5/manual/cfg-builders.html

Comment: better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229481/what-algorithm-does-buildbot-use-to-assign-builders-to-slaves

Comment: This is a bit of a follow up question: how to make sure that one particular build is not launched on slave n2 before the same build has finished on slave n1?

Comment: That can be controlled with interlocks: http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.5/manual/cfg-interlocks.html#interlocks

Comment: can you elaborate a bit? I've actually asked specific question for that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909394/how-to-lock-buildbot-build-to-finish-on-one-slave-before-stating-on-another
Because I probably not using the locks correctly.